# Correcting a wrong splitted in txt, python

Tags: python, split, python-re

I have several txt files which consists of different values, e.g:

```
TFF,BAP,VAP,DNAAF5,CDKN2B,PDE2D,SLC22A19,RBPJ,STAT1,TAP2,HLA-
```

I have probabely done a wrong split in the middle of the code, and it splitted by '-' so when I double click one value, it choose all line till the '-'. This mistake does not effect the function till this step. Now I need to count each value occurrens with "Counter" , and the count is wrong.

My code:

```
gene_calc = r'C:\Users\MrD\Top'
new_dir = r'C:\\Users\\MrD\\Br_Count\\Frequency\\'
for files in gene_calc:
    if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
        os.mkdir(new_dir)
    else:
        break
    os.chdir(gene_calc)
    for files in glob.glob(os.path.join('*.txt*')):
        #print(files) # iterating over files to check if prints
        with open(files) as f:
            content = (line for line in f.read().splitlines())
            list = Counter(Vol for Vol in content).most_common()
            with open(new_dir + files, "w") as output:
                output.write(str(list))
```

gene_calc folder consists of values as shown in the example above.

I couldn't resplit it (tried "if ',' in gene_list:" or reversing .reverse() but it's already a list with tuples)

Comment: I find it very hard to understand what exactly you're trying to do. Please reduce your code to the absolute minimum to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is good (atleast in my opinion..) the problem is that I cant count values seperated by " , " because it counted as a concatenated list

Comment: E.g: "XYZ,TGH" and "XYZ", seperately, XYZ will be counted as 1 with TGH (with TGH) and 1 alone. The answer should be 2, but it is not splitted correctly

Comment: just split the line first: `items = line.split(',')`

Comment: try `content = (item for line in f for item in line.split(','))`

Comment: Thank you Raphael, please post it as an answer with remove '\n' , content = (item for line in f for item in line.replace('\n', '').split(','))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the moment you are counting lines

```
content = (line for line in f.read().splitlines())
```

to count items you need a second split on ',':

```
content = (item for line in f for item in line.strip().split(','))
```